# javascript trying to produce an array that pushes blank entry every x number of entries

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble creating an array the way I would like. I need this for a google sheet script but that should not matter, it's just javscript.

I am making an array that represents days in a week, each entry in the array represents a day, the weekdays will have integers pushed to them, but the weekend days will have blank value pushed into the array.
The difficulty I am encountering, is that the start of the array could be any day of the week. So if the start day is a friday, and I am pushing 5 values, then the array will look something like this

```
[22,,,22,22] //fri=22, sat="", sun="", mon=22, tue=22
```

in my example oj jsbin, i can get it to work for one case, but not another case.
I will place the full code below the jsbin link

I'm hoping someone can tell me a better way to do what I am trying to do. Or help fix my poor code.

jsbin https://jsbin.com/poqumecafo/edit?js,console

```
var first = [, 500.0, 16.0, "Fri Jun 08 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018", 2.0, 24.0, "Sun Jun 03 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018", 0.0, "Tue Jun 19 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018"];

var second =  [, 1200.0, 25.0, "Sun Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018", 6.0, 17.0, "Fri May 25 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018", 5.0, "Wed Jul 18 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018"];
console.log('NOTE: day of week index - 6 = saturday, 0=Sunday, 1=mon, 2=tue, 3=wed, 4=thu, 5=fri');
console.log('-------------------------------------------');
var result1 = cleanArray(first);
console.log('result1 expected result = ,42,42,42,42,42,,,42,42,42,42,42,,,42');
console.log('day of week for result1 = ' + first[7])
console.log('result1= ' + result1);

var result2 = cleanArray(second);
console.log('result2 expected result = 31,,,31,31,31,31,31,,,31,31,31,31,31,,,31,31,31,31,31,,,31');
console.log('day of week for result2 = ' + second[7])
console.log('result2= ' + result2);

//found this function on the internet, takes 2 dates returns how many working days (minus weekend days)
function getBusinessDays(startDate, endDate) {
  //Logger.log('startdate ' + startDate + 'enddate ' + 'endDate' );
    var count = 0;
    var curDate = new Date(startDate);
    while (curDate <= new Date(endDate)) {
        var dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
        if(!((dayOfWeek == 6) || (dayOfWeek == 0)))
           count++;
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return count;
}

function cleanArray(ed){
//each row is [, 500.0, 16.0, Thu Jun 07 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018, 2.0, 23.0, Sat Jun 02 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018, 6.0, Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018]
// which is [options, CubicFeet, installDays, dateOfFirstInstall, rowIndex, colstartIndex, newStartDate, newStartDateDayofWeekNumber, finishDate]
//I have to return an array of the data that will actually show on the spreadsheet
//returns something like[[22,22,22,,,22,22,22],[11,11,11,,,11]] notice the empty cells are weekends
  //Logger.log('cleanarray incoming');
  //Logger.log(ed);

  var newCleanArr = []; //ready for new clean array

  // calculate how many working days (subtract weekends from total work days)
  var numWorkingDays = getBusinessDays(ed[6],ed[8]);
  //calculate how many cubic feet per working days
  var dailyCF = Math.round(ed[1]/numWorkingDays);


  for (var i = 0; i < ed[2]; i++) {
    //Logger.log('i='+i+' ed[7]=' + ed[7]); 
    if(i<1 && ed[7] == 0){
      //Logger.log('Sunday first');
      newCleanArr.push("");
    } else if( i<7 && i % 6 ===0 ){ //if sat or sun then make blank entry
      newCleanArr.push("");
      //Logger.log('saturday mod6=0');
    } else if (i<8 && i % 7 ===0 ){
      //Logger.log('sunday mod7=0');
        newCleanArr.push("");
    }  else if( i>7 && i % 6 ===1 ){ //if sat or sun then make blank entry
      newCleanArr.push("");
      //Logger.log('saturday mod6=0');
    } else if( i>8 && i % 6 ===2 ){ //if sat or sun then make blank entry
      newCleanArr.push("");
      //Logger.log('sunday mod6=0');
    } else {
      newCleanArr.push(dailyCF);
    }

  }


  //Logger.log('cleanArr');
  //Logger.log(newCleanArr);
  //Logger.log('numWorkingDays');
  //Logger.log(numWorkingDays);
  //Logger.log('dailyCF');
  //Logger.log(dailyCF);

  return newCleanArr;  
}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < ed[2]; i++) newCleanArr.push(i % 7 && (i + 1) % 7 ? dailyCF : "")` <- way easier

Comment: wow, yes waaaay easier. thanks very much Jonas W. for your ninja javascript skills. Here's a link to jsbin with solution https://jsbin.com/majicanewe/edit?js,console

Comment: not sure how to mark solved

Comment: actually not quite solved.... This does not factor in that the start day is different. Currently Jonas' code starts every group of days starting on a Sunday. Sometimes the start day is different.

Comment: here is a new jsbin showing that the second example does not match the expected result (start day is a friday in the second input array) https://jsbin.com/majicanewe/edit?js,console

Comment: I have found a way to handle the different start days see at this jsbin https://jsbin.com/majicanewe/edit?js,console , basically altered the for loop variables for (var i = ed[7]; i < ed[7] + ed[2]; i++)

Comment: which translates to... for (var i = dayOfWeekInteger; i < dayOfWeekInteger + numberOfDays; i++)